# I would like to creating a partition for ubuntu from macOS high sierra for a dual boot MacBook

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, boot-partition

I'm a noob to Ubuntu and looking for some advice on how I can set up my High Sierra 10.13.6 with a 30Gb bootable partition into Ubuntu 20.04. I have 285Gb free on my 500 Gb HDD which has a logical volume of Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

When in disk utility I get the following options for the format:
4 different APFS options which is for macOS on SSD's so think it's no good, 4 Mac OS options, again probably no good, ExFAT is that an option? MS-DOS (FAT) which is windows, once again I imagine is no good.

Is ExFAT an option to install Ubuntu on? If not, can you offer any suggestions of how I can get my MacBook to dual boot if at all possible?

I am in a state of transition in my life and how my laptop is set up is a reflection of that. I will more than likely move over, completely, to Ubuntu in the months to come but I have a lot of files that I need to research to figure out if there is an option to convert.

Any support or guidance is greatly appreciated.

~30Gb /Boot partition is now created and when I try to install on the ext4 file system it says no boot sector. There is already a boot sector for the MacOS, should I use the same, if so how? If not, do I create a new partition?

Comment: Start by reading this so you know what you are doing. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Only POSIX compliant filesystems can be used for Linux. That excludes anything made by microsoft. The default filesystem for Linux currently is ext4.

Comment: Right now you can create a partition with any file system. During installation of Ubuntu you can format that to ext4 (Ubuntu's default and recommended file system).

Comment: Thanks for the link David, always worth confirming knowledge!